# Generating comprehensive Audit log Reports for SharePoint Online Tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are looking to generate an audit log report(s) for entire SharePoint Online Tenant. Could someone provide guidance on how we can accomplish this? Specifically, I'm interested in obtaining information related to all usage including permissions/sharing/Deletions etc. within our SharePoint online Tenant. Any assistance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this would be to use Microsoft Purview's audit log functionality. Purview can provide comprehensive audit logs for all SharePoint sites in your tenant.

[Auditing solutions in Microsoft Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/purview/audit-solutions-overview)

Answer (score 0):

To generate an audit log report for the entire SharePoint Online Tenant, you can use the auditing and reporting features available in Microsoft cloud services.

To generate an audit log report for SharePoint Online, you can follow these steps:

1. Go to the Microsoft 365 compliance portal at https://compliance.microsoft.com.
2. Sign in using your work or school account.
3. In the left pane of the Microsoft Purview compliance portal, select Audit.
4. Under Activities, select SharePoint.
5. Select a date and time range to find the audit log events that occurred within that period.
6. Select Search to run the search.
7. When the search is finished running and the results are displayed, select Export results > Download all results. After you select the export option, a message at the bottom of the window prompts you to open or save the CSV file.
8. Select Save > Save as and save the CSV file to a folder on your local computer.